# PHP Include Wordpress after Cordova App is made

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have an issue with wordpress php includes after I've made an app via cordova for iOS. Basically, the code I have on the live website right now is:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-includes/wp-db.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
```

However this only works live. When I make the app, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` does not return the correct path to include the file I need. What path can I use to make sure these wordpress files are included in my external php file?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your directory structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the answer to this was to echo `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in a test php file and it came back with my root path, this allowed me to change it accordingly and it then worked remotely and not just locally.

Thanks for the help!